# perl file size calculation not working

Tags: perl, permissions, filesize

I am trying to write a simple perl script that will iterate through the regular files in a directory and calculate the total size of all the files put together. However, I am not able to get the actual size of the file, and I can't figure out why. Here is the relevant portion of the code. I put in print statements for debugging:

```
$totalsize = 0;
while ($_ = readdir (DH)) {
   print "current file is: $_\t";
   $cursize = -s $_;           
   print "size is: $cursize\n";
   $totalsize += $cursize;
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
current file is: test.pl    size is: 
current file is: prob12.pl  size is: 
current file is: prob13.pl  size is: 
current file is: prob14.pl  size is: 
current file is: prob15.pl  size is:
```

So the file size remains blank. I tried using `$cursize = $_` instead but the only effect of that was to retrieve the file sizes for the current and parent directories as 4096 bytes each; it still didn't get any of the actual file sizes for the regular files.

I have looked online and through a couple of books I have on perl, and it seems that perl isn't able to get the file sizes because the script can't read the files. I tested this by putting in an if statement:

```
print "Cannot read file $_\n" if (! -r _);
```

Sure enough for each file I got the error saying that the file could not be read. I do not understand why this is happening. The directory that has the files in question is a subdirectory of my home directory, and I am running the script as myself from another subdirectory in my home directory. I have read permissions to all the relevant files. I tried changing the mode on the files to 755 (from the previous 711), but I still got the `Cannot read file` output for each file.

I do not understand what's going on. Either I am mixed up about how permissions work when running a perl script, or I am mixed up about the proper way to use `-s _`. I appreciate your guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it isn't just your typo `-s _` instead of the correct `-s $_` then please remember that `readdir` returns file names relative to the directory you've opened with `opendir`. The proper way would be something like

```
my $base_dir = '/path/to/somewhere';
opendir DH, $base_dir or die;
while ($_ = readdir DH) {
  print "size of $_: " . (-s "$base_dir/$_") . "\n";
}
closedir DH;
```

You could also take a look at the core module [IO::Dir](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Dir.pm) which offers a `tie` way of accessing both the file names and the attributes in a simpler manner.

Comment: Thanks, Moritz! That was it. I put in the full path and bingo, it worked. I'll also look at IO::dir, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Also, I corrected the code sample to remove the typo and replaced `-s _` with `-s $_`. I had it correct in the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```
$cursize = -s _;
```

Should be:

```
$cursize = -s $_;
```

Comment: I tried that before posting the question, and as I explained, that didn't work either.

Comment: Maybe not, but FYI: statements like `-s _` or `-r _` will never be correct since `_` is not a variable.

Comment: @ElPaco It is the special file handle. If you do `-x $file; -s _`, then `-s` will affect the last file used.

Comment: Thanks ElPaco. I'm confused: I'm looking at this book `Beginning Perl` by James Lee (3rd ed) and on p 220 he has:

    `while ($_ = readdir (DH)) {
      print -s _ if -r and -f ;
    }`

and he says on the previous page that "_ is the default filehandle for perl's file tests." I do not understand the difference between the usage in his example, and what I'm doing here. Could you help me figure it out? Sorry to be dense.

Comment: Sounds like an error in the print if there's really no `$` before the `_`.

Comment: @TLP: Well look at that, something learnt today! :-) Thanks! Do you have any link describing this variable? I couldn't find anything in perlvar.

Comment: `print -s _ if -r and -f` works only because `-r` and `-f` are executed before `-s _`, and are applied to `$_` by default. Looks a bit confusing stated like that.

Comment: @ElPaco No, I could not find anything either, except a loose reference in `perldoc -f "-X"`

Comment: Oh I see! So some file test has to be applied to $file, and subsequent file tests can be applied to _ , which will be $file. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: `$file` or any variable, yes.

Comment: @verbose, @ElPaco  `_` reuses the latest stat($file). Doing file metadata queries is very expensive so Perl caches the information as usually you make several test to the same file.